# Very slow 'fetch documentation' in PyCharm

Tags: python, ide, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

Whenever I invoke Quick documentation that pops up yellow box in PyCharm, yellow box shows "Fetching documentation" for 4-8 seconds

- It happens even if I do it twice in a row. It's always slow - probably no caching?
- It also happens for built-in functions like `s=set(); s.add()`. Documentation for add takes 5 seconds
- My computer is not connected to internet

Comment: Did you find a solution?